# "Hook it home" meaning

Tags: idiom-meaning, poetry

I stumbled upon the idiom "hooking it home" in some of Bukowski's lines. Namely,

> the whores are there for young boys and old men;
> to the young boys they say,
> "don't be frightened, honey, here I'll put it in for you."
> and for the old guys
> they put on an act
> like you're really **hooking it home**.

The only related idiom meaning I found online is the following:

> to get a ride by hitchhiking. e.g., My car broke down and I had to hook it home.

Which does not seem suitable. I found some other references in sports articles, e.g.

> Six minutes later Hernández finally had the ball in Neuer's net, hooking it home with a brusque left-footed volley, only to be given offside.

This use seems more related since it has the "scoring" meaning.

On the other hand, I was thinking about a same-flavored idiom:
hammer (something) home, i.e,

> To make something extremely clear; to make someone understand or realize something, especially through forceful repetition.

What's your take on Bukowski's line? Is this (something like "forcefully scoring") another use of "hook it home"?

Comment: Yeap. Makes good sense.

Comment: It means: they are successfully penetrating the whores (no viagra, ha ha). God, Bukowski's gross.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Hook it home" is a term from football/soccer that apparently means to make a goal (with a challenging offensive maneuver.)

[(CNN)](http://www.cnn.com/2004/SPORT/football/01/20/england.monday.reut/)

> O'Brien got hold of a loose ball after Alan Shearer's strike had been
> blocked by a massed Fulham defence and hooked it home from two meters.

[(Irish Times)](https://www.irishtimes.com/sport/errors-undo-everton-1.170880)

> Campbell's challenge on Pavel Srnicek, as the pair went for a David
> Unsworth long ball, caused the goalkeeper to spill the ball to
> Jeffers, who hooked it home expertly from 20 yards.

[(DelawareOnline)](https://www.delawareonline.com/story/sports/high-school/2015/11/11/st-georges-coasts-against-st-es/75497614/)

> The senior forward hooked it home from an almost impossibly sharp
> angle to make it 2-0.

[(Marka.com)](https://www.marca.com/en/football/international-football/2017/01/29/588e5aae22601d531b8b45c1.html)

> Morocco failed to clear the bouncing ball and substitute Kahraba
> hooked it home from close range to book a semi-final against Burkina
> Faso on Wednesday.

This being used as metaphor by Bukowski means the *whores* are convincing the *old guys* they are really getting the job done in an expert way: that they are in fact pleasing the whores (*hooking it home*). They are scoring the goal by use of a skilled maneuver.